# Laravel Sanctum unauthenticated / token not saved

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, sanctum

I have a Laravel 6 application and installed Laravel Sanctum. Have followed these steps [1]. If I run `sanctum/token` via Postman I get a token as a response. When I open a protected route with this token set as bearer I always get unauthenticated.

When I look in the database the table `personal_access_tokens` is empty. While I create the token via:

```
$token = $user->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;
```

Anyone have an idea why it doesn't store the token in the database?

[1] https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#mobile-application-authentication

Comment: Hello @joost- cross check you have done configuration in karnel.php as well as HasApiToken Trait in your user model, as well as checkout your api.php it should have middleware auth.sanctum. if you have missed out any configuration checkout missing configuration and migrations through  sanctum document  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#mobile-application-authentication

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did al the steps you mention.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me. Place the following in your .htaccess file.

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```